# Is it mandatory to get approval for "publish_action" permission from Facebook even for testing the feature

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

Recently FB deprecated V1.0 of its Graph API and now the oldest working version is V2.0.

There is a major change in the "permissions" method of its API, Now if I want to use "publish_actions" then first I have to get approval for that by submitting the app (as per my findings).

Now I want to know that how can I start building a new app which will use "publish_actions" permission to post some content to the user wall? Can I use this feature without submitting the app as app is not yet developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions work without review for everyone with a role in the App, you can easily test it as App Admin/Developer/Tester.

Comment: Hi @luschn thanks, can you explain. Do i have to create a test app for that?